# How to remove the clickable transparent background from an image using python or python library?

Tags: python

[Default Image(befor cropping)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OUBR.png)

***How to convert this image to the cropped image ***
[Image after cropping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr4WV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pillow module in python to create transparent background.

```
from PIL import Image


def convertImage():
    img = Image.open("7OUBR.png")
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
  
    datas = img.getdata()
  
    newData = []
  
    for item in datas:
        if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append(item)
  
    img.putdata(newData)
    img.save("glass.png", format="png")
    print("Successful")
  
convertImage()
```